# How do you assign json objects in jq?

Tags: shell, jq, double-quotes

I tried `jq --argjson value '{"foo": "bar", "bar": "foo"}' ".x = $value" <<< "$json"`

Value of $json

```
{
   "x":{
      "foo": "hello"
   },
   "y":{
      "foo": "world"
   }
}
```

All I get is `jq: 1 compile error`

I expect:

```
{
   "x":{
      "foo": "bar",
      "bar": "foo"
   },
   "y":{
      "foo": "world"
   }
}
```

I've tried adding quotes around $value but it complains about bash quoting issues, and I believe it's trying to save the entire json object as a string

Comment: check your quotes

Comment: @hek2mgl Apologies, the quotes are right in my terminal but I mistyped them in the stackoverflow box

Comment: If the value is really hard-coded as shown, this would be simpler without using `--argjson`: `jq '.x = { foo: "bar", bar: "foo"}}' <<< "$json"`.

Comment: @chepner Not hard coded, I'm actually pulling a json object from json file, manipulating it, then copying it into a second json file. It's hard coded here because I know the copy from part works (tested it with echos and stuff). This is a middle step of the processing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dollar must be escaped when used inside a [double quoted string](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html) in the shell. Otherwise the shell would interpret it and expand the statement to:

```
jq --argjson value '{"foo": "bar", "bar": "foo"}' ".x = " <<< "$json"
                     empty since not set in the shell  ^^^
```

I suggest to wrap the jq command in single quotes:

```
jq --argjson value '{"foo": "bar", "bar": "foo"}' '.x = $value' <<< "$json"
```

Comment: looks your $json variable is malformed

Comment: You are correct (on both the malformed and the quotes). I just double checked it. Thanks. I'll accept this answer once stackoverflow lets me

Comment: Glad that it helped!